# Fill multidimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how to fill a multi-dimensional array in Excel VBA. A 1d array can be filled as follows:

```
Dim myarray as variant

myarray = Array("sheep", "goat", "chicken")
```

How would I fill each row separately for a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: You can fill a 2-dimensional array quickly by using a dynamic array and entering the data into a range on a worksheet. Then you can simply: `array = Range("Range")`. For more than 2 dimensions you have to read each value in individually.

Comment: That's a 1-D array you have there - did you really mean multidimensional?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
Dim a
a = [{1,2;3,4;5,6}]
```

Limitations:

- This only works with arrays of type `Variant`, because `[x]` is shorthand for `Evaluate("x")` which means that `x` is interpreted via Excel, and Excel only returns Variants. So declaring `Dim a As Variant` or an array `Dim a() As Variant` works fine. But not any other type of array e.g. `Dim a() As String` fails.
- This only works for one specific kind of multi-dimensional array, namely *two*-dimensional arrays. Not three-, four- etc. dimensional.

Comment: Really?? That's utterly cool! How on Earth haven't I ever seen this syntax before?!

Comment: It should be noted that this only works as shown.  A variable that is declared as an array will not be able to be loaded this way.  You'll get a compile error: "Can't assign to array."

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, I just tried it exactly that way and it fails with a compile error.

Comment: `Dim a() As Variant: a = [{1,2;3,4;5,6}]` compiles and executes just fine at my end? Office 2010