# MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY INITIALISATION in EXCEL-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to initialize a 2D array in VBA - Excel using this code. I have seen this Microsoft support site but its not working.

ERROR : EXPECTED : END OF STATEMENT....

```
Sub NUM ()

Dim Nominal_dia As Integer

Dim torque As Double


Dim numbers = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you look at the link that was provided in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662891/initialising-multidimentional-array-in-vb)?  look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807568/fill-multidimensional-array) it gives you the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner still not working ,,,plz run that code ...and reply

Comment: Between my comments yesterday and the link provided by @TimWilliams you should be able to make the changes to work.

Comment: If you cannot make the code work then there is something else that is wrong.  The code works for me.

Comment: Are you working in Excel, or in Access ?  They're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
Sub NUM()
    Dim Nominal_dia As Integer 'Not used variable
    Dim torque As Double 'Not used variable
    Dim numbers

    numbers = [{1, 2;3, 4;5, 6}]
End Sub
```

Comment: ERROR : external name not defined